# Maven Dependency not working properly with intellij

Tags: java, maven, kotlin, intellij-idea

so like im trying to make like a library for util shit and like for some reason when i import it into maven it imports the dependencies bc they are shaded in but it doesnt import the libarys actual code. At First the Dependencies were not even imported but I got it working by fiddling with the pom.xml. If I use the library in code it errors in the IntelliJ IDE but maven still builds it properly which is very weird.

https://github.com/MrEnxo/Utilase

Github for code ^

Well intellij is kinda supposed to know the dependcies and stuff

Answer (score 0):

you can try delete the pom.lastupdate file in maven repository and reimport

Comment: yeah no that does nothing.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).